# Return the other users usernames and thumbnails in group private messages

Tags: php, mysql

**My data** (sqlfiddle is currently down):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `user_id`           INT(11)         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `first_name`        VARCHAR(25)     NOT NULL,
    `last_name`         VARCHAR(25)     NOT NULL,
    `username`          VARCHAR(25)     NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `email`             VARCHAR(60)     NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `password`          VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    `dob`               VARCHAR(10)     NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

insert into users values
(0, 'Amy','Stew', 'amy0','amy@mail.com','pwd','dob'),
(1, 'John','Marks', 'john1','john@mail.com','pwd','dob'),
(2, 'Wendy','Crow', 'wendy2','wendy@mail.com','pwd','dob'),
(3, 'Steve','Sky', 'steve3','steve@mail.com','pwd','dob'),
(4, 'Sean','Lake', 'sean4','sean@mail.com','pwd','dob');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS privatemessages (
    `id`                INT(11)         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `fromuser`          INT(11)         NOT NULL,
    `touser`            INT(11)         NOT NULL,
    `message`           TEXT            NOT NULL,
    `readit`            ENUM(NULL,'1')  NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `deleted_fromuser`  ENUM(NULL,'1')  NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `deleted_touser`    ENUM(NULL,'1')  NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `date_time`         DATETIME        NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (fromuser) REFERENCES users(user_id),
FOREIGN KEY (touser) REFERENCES users(user_id),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

insert into privatemessages values 
(0,0,3,'0->3 message',NULL,NULL,NULL,now()),
(1,3,0,'3->0 message',NULL,NULL,NULL,now()),
(2,1,2,'1->2 message',NULL,NULL,NULL,now()),
(3,3,1,'3->1 message',NULL,NULL,NULL,now()),
(4,4,3,'4->3 message',NULL,NULL,NULL,now()),
(5,3,4,'3->4 message',NULL,NULL,NULL,now()),
(6,3,4,'3->4 message',NULL,NULL,NULL,now());

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `photos` (
    `id`            INT(11)         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `user_id`       INT(11)         NOT NULL,
    `image`         VARCHAR(200),
    `thumb`         VARCHAR(200),
    `date`          DATETIME,
    `profile`       ENUM('0', '1')  NOT NULL DEFAULT "0",
    `approved`      ENUM('0', '1')  NOT NULL DEFAULT "0",
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

insert into photos values
(0,0, 'amy-image.jpg','amy-thumb-image.jpg',now(),1,1),
(1,1, 'john-image.jpg','john-thumb-image.jpg',now(),1,1),
(2,2, 'wendy-image.jpg','wendy-thumb-image.jpg',now(),1,1),
(3,3, 'steve-image.jpg','steve-thumb-image.jpg',now(),1,1),
(4,4, 'sean-image.jpg','sean-thumb-image.jpg',now(),1,1);
```

**PHP**:

```
if (isset($_GET ['messages'])){
// Get the user id and
// Commented out durring testing - $id = $_GET['messages'];
// For testing id is set to 3
$id = 3;
// fetch all the messages from/to user 3 and join them together by each conversation to display as a single conversation button/link
$result = mysqli_query($DBcon, "
SELECT 
    pm1.id,
    pm1.fromuser,
    pm1.touser,
    pm1.message,
    pm1.readit,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(pm1.date_time),
    us.user_id,
    us.username,
    pt.user_id, 
    pt.thumb,
    pt.profile 
FROM 
    privatemessages pm1
    INNER JOIN
     users us 
     ON us.user_id = pm1.touser
INNER JOIN 
     photos pt 
     ON pt.user_id = pm1.touser
WHERE 
    pm1.date_time = (
        Select max(pm1.date_time) 
    FROM 
        privatemessages pm2 
    WHERE 
        pm1.fromuser = pm2.fromuser 
    AND 
        pm1.touser = pm2.touser
    AND 
        (touser = '$id' or fromuser = '$id')
    )
GROUP BY
    pm1.fromuser, 
    pm1.touser
ORDER BY pm1.id DESC
LIMIT 10
");


    // check there are any messages
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {           
            $fromuser=$item['fromuser'];
            $touser=$item['touser'];
            $username=$item['username'];
            $thumb=$item['thumb'];

            // if user doesn't have profile picture then use "default.jpg" thumbnail
            if (is_null($thumb)) {
                $thumb = 'default'; 
                $slash='';
                $image = '';
            } else {
                $image=$touser;
                $slash="/";
                $thumb=$thumb;
            }
            // display the messages
            echo "<div class='row messages'>";
            echo "<a class='message-link' data-read='" . $touser . "' href='message.php?from_id=" . $fromuser . "&to_id=" . $touser . "'>";
            echo "<div class='col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 message-block'>";
            echo "<img class='message-photo' src='http://127.0.0.1/socialnetwork/uploads/images/thumbs/" . $image . "" . $slash . "" . $thumb . ".jpg''>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<div class='col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-9 message-block'>";
            echo "<span class='message-meta message-title'>" . $username . "</span>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</a>";
            echo "<div class='col-xs-7 col-sm-10 col-md-2 message-block'>";
            echo "<span class='message-meta float-right'><a href='components/delete-messages.php?delmessageshistory&user_id=" . $fromuser . "&member_id=" . $touser . "' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right'>Delete</a></span>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp;ERROR - NOTHING FOUND $DBcon->error</div>";
    }
}
```

I want to join these tables where the user's ID can be found in both `fromuser` and `touser` fields of `privatemessages` table so that I can get all sent messages and received messages to and from some user.

I want to pull the corresponding `username` and `thumb` fields from the other two tables.

I feel like I'm going around in circles now.

Query returns results but the usernames are all the same, IDs are the same but they all have different photos. Help

**What I want**

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id | fromuser | touser | message        | readit | deleted_fromuser | deleted_touser | date_time         |
+----+----------+--------+----------------+--------+------------------+----------------+-------------------+
|  4 |    4     |   3    | "4->3 message" |  NULL  |       NULL       |      NULL      |2017-02-19 17:20:00|
|  5 |    3     |   4    | "3->4 message" |  NULL  |       NULL       |      NULL      |2017-02-19 18:25:00|
|  6 |    3     |   4    | "3->4 message" |  NULL  |       NULL       |      NULL      |2017-02-19 21:04:41|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  0 |    0     |   3    | "0->3 message" |  NULL  |       NULL       |      NULL      |2017-02-19 17:20:09|
|  1 |    3     |   0    | "3->0 message" |  NULL  |       NULL       |      NULL      |2017-02-19 17:24:41|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  3 |    3     |   1    | "3->1 message" |  NULL  |       NULL       |      NULL      |2017-02-19 13:12:00|
```

Conversation between user 3 & 4
Conversation between user 3 & 0
Conversation between user 3 & 1

```
<div class="row messages-container">

    <div class='row messages'>
        <a class='message-link' data-read='3' href='message.php?from_id=4&to_id=3'>
            <div class='col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 message-block'>";
                <img class='message-photo' src='http://127.0.0.1/socialnetwork/uploads/images/thumbs/4/sean-thumb-image.jpg''>
            </div>
            <div class='col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-9 message-block'>
                <span class='message-meta message-title'>steve3</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class='col-xs-7 col-sm-10 col-md-2 message-block'>
            <span class='message-meta float-right'>
                <a href='components/delete-messages.php?delmessageshistory&user_id=4&member_id=3' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right'>Delete</a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='row messages'>
        <a class='message-link' data-read='3' href='message.php?from_id=0&to_id=3'>
            <div class='col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 message-block'>";
                <img class='message-photo' src='http://127.0.0.1/socialnetwork/uploads/images/thumbs/0/amy-thumb-image.jpg''>
            </div>
            <div class='col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-9 message-block'>
                <span class='message-meta message-title'>amy0</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class='col-xs-7 col-sm-10 col-md-2 message-block'>
            <span class='message-meta float-right'>
                <a href='components/delete-messages.php?delmessageshistory&user_id=0&member_id=3' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right'>Delete</a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='row messages'>
        <a class='message-link' data-read='3' href='message.php?from_id=3&to_id=1'>
            <div class='col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 message-block'>";
                <img class='message-photo' src='http://127.0.0.1/socialnetwork/uploads/images/thumbs/1/john-thumb-image.jpg''>
            </div>
            <div class='col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-9 message-block'>
                <span class='message-meta message-title'>john1</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class='col-xs-7 col-sm-10 col-md-2 message-block'>
            <span class='message-meta float-right'>
                <a href='components/delete-messages.php?delmessageshistory&user_id=3&member_id=1' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right'>Delete</a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div><!-- END messages-container -->
```

**What I am getting**

```
<div class="row messages-container">

    <div class='row messages'>
        <a class='message-link' data-read='3' href='message.php?from_id=4&to_id=3'>
            <div class='col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 message-block'>";
                <img class='message-photo' src='http://127.0.0.1/socialnetwork/uploads/images/thumbs/4/sean-thumb-image.jpg''>
            </div>
            <div class='col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-9 message-block'>
                <span class='message-meta message-title'>steve3</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class='col-xs-7 col-sm-10 col-md-2 message-block'>
            <span class='message-meta float-right'>
                <a href='components/delete-messages.php?delmessageshistory&user_id=4&member_id=3' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right'>Delete</a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='row messages'>
        <a class='message-link' data-read='3' href='message.php?from_id=0&to_id=3'>
            <div class='col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 message-block'>";
                <img class='message-photo' src='http://127.0.0.1/socialnetwork/uploads/images/thumbs/0/amy-thumb-image.jpg''>
            </div>
            <div class='col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-9 message-block'>
                <span class='message-meta message-title'>amy0</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class='col-xs-7 col-sm-10 col-md-2 message-block'>
            <span class='message-meta float-right'>
                <a href='components/delete-messages.php?delmessageshistory&user_id=0&member_id=3' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right'>Delete</a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='row messages'>
        <a class='message-link' data-read='3' href='message.php?from_id=3&to_id=1'>
            <div class='col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 message-block'>";
                <img class='message-photo' src='http://127.0.0.1/socialnetwork/uploads/images/thumbs/3/steve-thumb-image.jpg''>
            </div>
            <div class='col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-9 message-block'>
                <span class='message-meta message-title'>steve3</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class='col-xs-7 col-sm-10 col-md-2 message-block'>
            <span class='message-meta float-right'>
                <a href='components/delete-messages.php?delmessageshistory&user_id=3&member_id=1' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right'>Delete</a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div><!-- END messages-container -->
```

The third message is an outgoing message from steve3 to john1, what I'm getting printing is steve3's username rather than the recipient's username which in that case should be john1.
I want to return results where steve3 has either sent a user a message or has been sent a message by another user but in the case where steve3 sends the message I don't want the message link to read username "steve3" with steve's thumbnail showing, I want the other user's username and image.

Comment: Is your question mostly about updating the query to achieve the result dataset, or do you also want to know about the HTML output too? It appears that the HTML below heading/line: `Conversation between user 3 & 4 Conversation between user 3 & 0 Conversation between user 3 & 1` only contains 3 messages (i.e. 4->3, 0->3, 3->1). Please update your post with the answers. Thanks!

Comment: @SamOnela the HTML output bellow that line is part of the heading "What I want" and the second HTML output is part of the heading "What I'm getting".

Comment: Yes, however, in the output SQL results there are 5 rows, and looking at the PHP code, it iterates over those results, adding a div for each one (i.e. `<div class='row messages'>`). Yet in the HTML there only appear to be 3 of those divs...